# XPath expression works in Chrome's developer tools feature and not in my code

Tags: php, google-chrome, xpath

I recently started exploring the creation of Web crawlers. I chose to work with PHP for no particular reason. Got my turducken of a cURL instance inside a DOMDocument inside a DOMXpath. And I was pleased to find that using XPath is quite simple.

Unfortunately, despite its flawless record when I use it in Chrome's developer tools feature, it doesn't always return results in my code. The same expression will work in the former environment and not in the latter.

For a specific example, I cannot get my paws on the title beneath the video on a YouTube page.

My question: Why might an XPath expression return a result in Chrome's developer tools feature and get me nothing but a zero in my code? Here's my stuff and a couple of expressions that I've tried:

```
<?php

  $ch = curl_init("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIPGkrlM3R8");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $curl = curl_exec($ch);

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($curl);

  $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);


  $results = $xpath->query("//span[@id='eow-title']");
  //$results = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1/span");

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    print_r($result->nodeValue . "<br>");
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already on the right track (you're targeting the element correctly anyway). Typecast it with `(string)`:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIPGkrlM3R8");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$results = trim((string) $xpath->query("//span[@id='eow-title']")->item(0)->nodeValue);
echo $results; // Scraping Websites with PHP using DOMXpath and DOMDocument Part 2: Building an XPath Class
```

[**Sample Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VXdqU7)

Comment: Firstly, thank ya! Although it's telling me that I can't get the node value of a non-object. I took off "->nodeValue" and did the var_dump() thing, and it says that the string has no length. Maybe it's a ghost. :)

Comment: @Savannah i added a full code and a demo check the revision

Comment: Ah, excellent! Thanks very much for helping me out with that.